# Stumped on migration

Tags: php, mysql, migration

I'm migrating a site from my server to a client's Bluehost (ugh) account. I've tried using

- All In One WP Migrate
- BackupBuddy
- manual migration (copying files & exporting a db using WP Migrate DB)

These are the stats on my server:

```
Apache Version  2.2.24
PHP Version 5.3.26
MySQL Version   5.6.28-76.1
```

And the client's server:

```
Apache  2.2.31
PHP 5.2.17
MySQL   5.5.42
```

I did set the php.ini on the client server to update to php 5.4. I presume (maybe incorrectly) that the difference in MySQL version shouldn't matter.

Every time I'm getting an HTTP 500 Error (though after the last attempt it's an Internal Server 500 on the home page & the HTTP 500 Error everywhere else).

I renamed the .htaccess - no dice. Removed the php.ini - no dice. The database prefix is different, and I set wp-config to use the extension from the dev site.

Usually these migrations are pretty easy so I'm stumped. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to turn `WP_DEBUG` on in your `wp-config.php`:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
```

That'll help a lot with working out where that 500 error is coming from. Based on the PHP versions you've mentioned, I'm 99.999% sure that the error is due to a feature that isn't available in PHP 5.2.17. You're probably looking at either [shorthand array notation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) (eg. `$array = [];` - although this was added in PHP 5.4.0 so probably isn't the problem in your case, given you're coming from 5.3.26), or one of [anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php), [Namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php) or [array_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace.php), which were all added in PHP 5.3.0.

Having WP_DEBUG on will point you to where that error is being caused. If you've written the code yourself you could replace it with an older alternative (eg. longer array notation, or a non-anonymous function), or if it's possible on the server you're on you could upgrade the PHP version.

As an example, to replace an **anonymous function**, you'd want to change something like this:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', function($content){ return 'hello'; });
```

to this:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_content_function');

function my_content_function($content){ return 'hello'; }
```

Other things worth trying include:

- Commenting out lines in your `.htaccess` (add `#` to the start of the line) that aren't between the `# START WordPress` and `# END WordPress` lines
- [Resetting your file permissions](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions#Permission_Scheme_for_WordPress)
- The usual disabling all plugins - and changing themes - to see if the problem goes away (if you can't access the admin, you can just rename the individual plugin or theme folders to disable them)

Comment: The front page is still showing a 500 internal server error. /wp-login.php etc are now showing:


`Warning: Unexpected character in input: '\' (ASCII=92) state=1 in /home2/distriw0/public_html/wp-content/plugins/shortpixel-image-optimiser/wp-shortpixel.php on line 1659

Fatal error: Call to undefined function array_replace() in /home2/distriw0/public_html/wp-content/plugins/query-wrangler/includes/class-qw-settings.php on line 28'`

Comment: OK - I've made some progress. After setting the php to 5.4, I was able to login to the backend. The front end is still a 500 Internal Server Error.

Comment: It's not the theme or plugins - I switched to the default WP theme and renamed the plugin folder, still had a 500 error on the front end. The errors from the 2 plugins are gone & I'm able to login to /wp-admin no problem.

Comment: I tried reinstalling 4.5.3 from /wp-admin as well.

Comment: I got the site working after 1) changing php to 5.4 and 2) resetting the file permissions on all files & folders. Oddly, the site still looked a little different than the dev site, I may have missed reactivating a plugin or two.

Comment: @ArpLaszlo Glad you solved it! I've edited this post to fold in some of the solutions, condense it a little and hopefully make it useful to others who come across it. I've cleaned up my comments too.

Answer (score 0):

The absolute best way to migrate is:

1. get access to your mysql server
2. make a dump of the database
3. get access to your file server
4. zip your /wp-content folder
5. upload your zip and sql files to the new server
6. uncompress the /wp-content file
7. load the old dump into your new database server
8. modify your wp-config.php and point to the new database server

*source: my own experience throught a large list of websites.*

PS and important: don't dump through a WP plugin!!

Comment: What do you for url changes - do it through sql commands?

Comment: yes, you can use a simple

```UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = REPLACE(guid, 'old_url', 'new_url')```

isn't so good for SEO but also you can try (https://wordpress.org/plugins/velvet-blues-update-urls/) Velvet Blues Update URLs, I found it today and works fine in +100000 post site :)

Comment: You shouldn't change the guid field. See https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL#Important_GUID_Note

Answer (score -1):

Try using the plugin called Duplicator https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/

I always it to migrate website. You should not face any problems with this one

As for the errors you are facing there might be additional files that blue host might keep. Do check for any unwanted files or folders

Comment: I got the site working after 1) changing php to 5.4 and 2) resetting the file permissions on all files & folders. Oddly, the site still looked a little different than the dev site, I may have missed reactivating a plugin or two.

Comment: Please, do **not** post link only parts – even if it answers the question. As soon as a link is dead, your answer is worthless.